# Using Class UI's with IF Statements

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently trying to create a custom UI dialogs with google app scripts.

Here's my current script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cell = e.range;
  var cellColumn = cell.getColumn();
  var cellSheet = cell.getSheet().getName();
  var cellValue = e.value;
  var sheet = "System_Info"; 


  if (cellSheet !== sheet) {
  if (cellColumn === 4 || cellColumn === 5) {
    if (cellValue === "PT1 - Induction Training") {
      Browser.msgBox('Course Information', "PT1 - Induction Training:\\n\\nType: Theory \\n\\nTime Needed: 15-20 Minutes\\n\\n Learning Resource/Manual: BBACT, Forum Post: Rules for Officers" , Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);  //Add the course name and the message that I want to popup. Course name should be exactly the same as in the list (case sensitive)
    } 

    else if (cellValue === "PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 1") {
      Browser.msgBox("PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 1 - Starting a Patrol/Loadouts: \\n\\nType: Practical \\n\\nTime Needed: 15-20 Minutes\\n\\n Learning Resource/Manual: PT2 Guide \\n Section: 1, 2");  //// add as many "else if" conditions as you want"
    } else if (cellValue === "PT2 - Traffic & Communications - Part 2") {
  } 


      else if (cellValue === undefined) {  }
    else {
      Browser.msgBox('You have entered an invalid data, please select correct data corresponding to the Column.');   //This is in case they put a wrong course name
    }
  }
}
}
```

Now, I have found that browser message boxes cannot support custom buttons but a UI can.

I'm trying to add this to the code for each if statement, however each one will be different.

Code:

```
// Display a dialog box with a message and "Ok" and "Guide" buttons. The user can also close the
 // dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.alert("PT1 - Induction Training:\\n\\nType: Theory \\n\\nTime Needed: 15-20 Minutes\\n\\n Learning Resource/Manual: BBACT, Forum Post: Rules for Officers", ui.ButtonSet.OK_GUIDE);

 // Process the user's response.
 if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
   Logger.log('The user clicked "Ok."');
 } else {
   Logger.log('The user clicked "Guide", open up guide link: www.britishborders.co.uk/laws');
 }
```

Essentially, I want a custom dialog to appear when a particular value is inputted as seen in the IF statements. In that dialog box, it will show course information as well as the ability to close the box by selecting, "Ok" and also they can view the guide by clicking, "Guide".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this looks identical to another question from yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extremely similar to the question you asked yesterday, which you should have responded to instead of making a new question. That being said, what I provided clearly wasn't helpful enough - you can't do ui.ButtonSet.MadeUpButton. You need to use HTML to serve custom content, with a button:

```
function buttonDemo(){
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput('<p>A change of speed, a change of style...</p><br><button onclick="google.script.run.logMe()">Close</button>')
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
     .setWidth(250)
     .setHeight(300);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
}
function logMe(){
Logger.log("You've been logged")
}
```

Try running that code - when you click the button, logMe() is run. You can append whatever HTML you want to the htmlOutput variable inside of your if statements. You can have two buttons which either call separate functions, or pass a variable to one function. For example, google.script.run.logMe(selectedOption). Hopefully that help resolves the issue you're having...

Comment: Thankyou for your help. Sorry, I should of responded to your comment before posting a new question. Remembered for next time! :)

Comment: Just a quick one, I have manipulated what you have provided however, I'm struggling to make a button open a new tab with a specific link when clicked... So, I currently have '<br><button onclick="window.open(https://www.britishborders.co.uk/laws)">Guide</button>'       I now want to make a button open a new link, this isn't working so what would you suggest?

Comment: In that case, you should do <a class="button" href="Google.com">Click me</a>. You may need to include this stylesheet for that though: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

Comment: Ok that worked thanks! :) Last problem, after the first if statement when the html output is done, it ignores all other if statements. You can view a copy of what I'm trying to do: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WGiPtA_k5Czt8_vZSEbw3w2znj-l0MXwLPGCoRRComg/edit#gid=1013580820)         To view the script, just go Tools --> Script Editor (you probably know this but just in case.

Comment: @ShaunCockram `if (cellSheet !== sheet){` at line 9 has a closing bracket at line 36 - the code that follows will only execute if someone **is** on the sheet "System_Info". You should use Logger.log() to track what's happening in your code, when something doesn't work as it should, you can view the logs to see why (it's probably one character in the wrong place)